# REST sub/child resource a single entity

Tags: rest, http, restful-url

I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to model a child resource.

Take the example of books with an author. You can have N books each with only one author.

```
/books GET
/books POST
/books/id PUT
/books/id DELETE
```

So far easy.

What about adding an author to a book. Removed at least for this example each book only has one author

```
/books/id/author POST
```

That seems confusing to me as POST usually means create. In the case where an author is already set the user of the api migh think they are just creating a new author when in fact they are deleting the old author and replacing it with a new author.

That leaves me with

```
/books/id/author PUT
```

meaning update the author resource for that book. Makes a little more sense. But what about the first time when no author exist?  Not really an update but the initial create?  Maybe just thinking about it is update a nil author.

Should this even be a child resource?  It's going to be a complex object so kind of makes sense. Although I guess you can't have a book without an author. So should I not model as child resource and say that you pass the author object when you create or modify the book resource.

Final thought. I don't think I will model authors as a root resource. So at least in this case they will only ever exist under a book resource. And again only one author per book.

Comment: "But what about the first time when no author exist?" --- it still is semantic. `PUT` just puts data to a resource, regardless if it existed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what about the first time when no author exist? Not really an update but the initial create?

Using `PUT /books/id/author` to initially create the author looks fine to me. As you can use `PUT /books/client-supplied-id` to create a book with an ID supplied by the client, you can create the author of a book which is identified by the known path segment `author`.

Since you write that an author will only exist as a component of a book, this URL scheme is fine.